# i can't install every gem (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

i can't install every gem , i checked reference = [rubygem](https://rubygems.org/)

[command image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3K2O.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need update

```
gem update --system
```